# Python Django Celery Integration with Azure Service Bus

Tags: python, django, azure, celery, azureservicebus

Have you used Azure Service bus Queues as a message broker of Celery for a Django Project? What are the advantages and disadvantages of it?
There is not much documentation for this integration. Does celery support Azure Service Bus?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Python Django Celery with Azure Service Bus. Both Azure Service Bus and Celery can be categorized as **"Message Queue"** tools. [This](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/whatsnew-5.1.html#id17) document describes the current stable version of Celery support for Azure Service Bus 7.0.0 using Kombu v5.1.0

Checkout [azure-servicebus/samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples) to get more sample code to build on.

**Refer:** kombu - [Messaging library for Python](https://github.com/celery/kombu#kombu---messaging-library-for-python) and [Azure Service Bus Message Queue transport module for kombu.](https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/latest/reference/kombu.transport.azureservicebus.html)